# triathlon handlebars for ultegra di2

Tags: handlebars, electronics, triathlon

I recently bought a [Canyon AL 9.0 Di2](http://www.canyon.com/_en/roadbikes/bike.html?b=3081) bike and would like to mount a triathlon handlebars on it. My ultimate desire would be able to have the gear switchers both on the triathlon and the bike's handlebars. My questions are :

(i) Is there gear to achieve all the above without cutting and soldering the wires and doing that type of nasty work

(ii) If it is not possible to have it the (i) option, maybe one can do it with cutting and soldering the wire?

(iii) Any suggestions for the handlebars for this type of bike? I have a rather weird body-geometry (with rather short legs and rather long torso).

Any comments are very helpful.

Comment: I don't see how (i) is "nasty work".  It should be quite simple and straight-forward.  I've never looked closely as an electronic shifter setup, but it may even be possible to do it without cutting wires (by putting multiple wires under one screw terminal, eg), or someone may sell a harness adapter to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want are [satellite shifters](http://bike.shimano.com.sg/publish/content/global_cycle/en/sg/index/news/dura-ace_di2_satellite.html) or the [TT shifters](http://bike.shimano.com/publish/content/global_cycle/en/us/index/products/road/dura_ace.html).

I believe they just plug into the standard brake/shifters.

Comment: those tt shifters look beautifully engineered. I daren't look at the cost!

Comment: On the bike handlebars there's already ultegra di2 shifters, so I suppose I do not need those shifters for the handlebars that came with the bike. What I need is a triathlon handlebars and the shifters for the triathlon handlebars. I am not sure, but the urls do not really point to triathlon handlebars. Do you have [Shifter
SW-9071](http://bike.shimano.com/publish/content/global_cycle/en/us/index/products/road/dura_ace.html) in mind? Is there anything availabe on the market that is a bit more afordable?

Comment: Yes, or the SW-R671. Sorry, didn't realise I couldn't link directly to the individual product.

Comment: @alex thanks. I still am looking for something a bit more afordable :)

Answer (score 0):

As you stated, It is not possible to have shifters both in the road style handlebars (brifters) as well as at the bar end of the aero bars. The only option for this is the [Shimano Dura Ace Di2](http://bike.shimano.com/publish/content/global_cycle/en/us/index/products/road/dura_ace.html) shifting system, which judging by your comments, is not within your budget.  I would recommend just putting some Aero bars on the bike [Like these](http://www.profile-design.com/profile-design/products/aerobars/aluminum-aerobars/t3-plus.html).